# Connecting Jenkins agent on Windows failed with connection timeout

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

Connecting Jenkins agent on windows failed with connection timeout.

Environment:
Windows server 2003 R2
Java6

Master: Linux
Slave: Windows

I tried to run it as jnlp and also java -jar cmd but it fails consistently.

```
INFO: Connecting to [ec2-machine_url]:4317
5 (retrying:2)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.connect(Engine.java:304)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:193)
```

Comment: Did you try to go through logs? You should find there more information about this problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't give much information, but from the error message, you seem to be suggesting that your build machine is running on Amazon EC2.

In that case, it's likely that your security group for the EC2 instance isn't allowing TCP connections from your Jenkins master server to port 4317 on the build machine.

Check that your security group is configured correctly and, if you're using the JNLP client, you can also ensure that the Jenkins master server listens on a fixed port, to make firewall configuration easier:

Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security > Enable security > TCP port for JNLP agents: Fixed

Comment: I setup jenkins master build server in linux [RHEL - EC2] and slave in windows[another cloud network].Thing is it was working fine before. I checked the security group and it is configured correctly [port 4317 - enabled & open]. Also enabled security TCP port for JNLP agants in jenkins. But still i'm getting the connection timeout exception.

Comment: @Hariharan Are you able to connect to port 4317 if you manually try it with telnet when logged in to the Windows machine?

Comment: Thanks @Christopher, solved this issue. Just need to set TCP port 4317 in EC2 security group to be accessible from anywhere since my slave agent  running in another Cloud platform.