# connection timeout when connecting slave (windows) to master (linux)

Tags: jenkins

I',m struggling to connect my windows slave to the Jenkins server (Linux), but with no luck. Tried many ways, resolved few, and finally, I'm stuck with a connection timeout. I see some of the post mentioning similar problems has no response.

**Exception log**

```
C:\jenkinsbin>java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl https://<jenkins.com>/comput
er/SFDC%20Node/slave-agent.jnlp -secret <****> -workDir "C:/jenkinsslavesfdc"
Feb 22, 2018 2:16:40 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeW
orkDir
INFO: Using C:\jenkinsslavesfdc\remoting as a remoting work directory
Both error and output logs will be printed to C:\jenkinsslavesfdc\remoting
Feb 22, 2018 2:16:41 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main createEngine
INFO: Setting up slave: SFDC Node
Feb 22, 2018 2:16:41 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener <init>
INFO: Jenkins agent is running in headless mode.
Feb 22, 2018 2:16:41 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeW
orkDir
INFO: Using C:\jenkinsslavesfdc\remoting as a remoting work directory
Feb 22, 2018 2:16:41 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [https://<jenkins.com>/]
Feb 22, 2018 2:16:43 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver
resolve
INFO: Remoting server accepts the following protocols: [JNLP4-connect, JNLP-conn
ect, Ping, JNLP2-connect]
Feb 22, 2018 2:16:43 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Agent discovery successful
  Agent address: <jenkins.com>
  Agent port:    55202
  Identity:      80:e0:51:b6:65:64:7b:78:ce:ea:7d:c2:9d:27:5b:2a
Feb 22, 2018 2:16:43 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
Feb 22, 2018 2:16:43 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to jenkins.com:55202
Feb 22, 2018 2:17:14 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to jenkins.com:55202 (retrying:2)
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to jenkins.com:55202
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpoint.open(JnlpAgentEndpoin
t.java:243)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.connect(Engine.java:667)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:528)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:451)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(Unknown Source)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpoint.open(JnlpAgentEndpoin
t.java:204)
        ... 3 more
```

**Few observations** from my end:

1. Slave is able to ping jenkins.com
2. Port 55202 added under firewall (inbound & outbound) rule to allow connections in slave.
3. Port 55202 is listening in master
4. Also, since I’m using windows as my slave, is it suggested to use only java web start launch?
5. Tried traceroute in slave, but very inconsistent.
6. Is iptables in master are restricted for any non-identical subnets? I guess the master is not responding and hence connection timeout?

Comment: Are you sure you want your Jenkins slave to connect to "jenkins.com"? Shouldn't you have a local Jenkins server with a static IP or local DNS name that you want your slave to connect to?

Comment: it is not for my local Jenkins, for ex if: 'jenkins.com' (DNS name is different) is my Jenkins server which is basically a Linux server, I wanted to connect my slave machine (windows) to that. Also, I do not have admin access to that server, only through URL, I will have to access master.

Answer (score 0):

Rohit,

Can you check if this is relevant in your case?
[Connecting Jenkins slave agent on windows failed with connection timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363816/connecting-jenkins-slave-agent-on-windows-failed-with-connection-timeout)

W.r.t. 2: You can completely turn off firewall if you are working in a same secured network.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I see they have resolved by adding a port to the security group in the master, let me check on this. By the way in Jenkins, the port 55202 is fixed in my case as well.