# Failed to obtain slave-agent.jnlp. Connection timed out

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I have Jenkins configured on a server. I am creating a Windows agent to be configured with this Jenkins.
On windows agent, when I run:

```
java -Xms16g -Xmx16g -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://<jenkins IP>:8080/jenkins/computer/<slave IP>/slave-agent.jnlp -secret <secret>
Failing to obtain http://<jenkins IP>:8080/jenkins/computer/<slave IP>/slave-agent.jnlp?encrypt=true
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Also, I am unable to open the Jenkins URL on the agent machine. I am able to open Jenkins URL on my local computer.
I also tried downloading the `slave-agent.jnlp` locally and copied it to Windows agent and tried running it there, but I get the following error :

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: http://<jenkins IP>:8080/jenkins/jnlpJars/remoting.jar
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting Jenkins slave agent on windows failed with connection timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363816/connecting-jenkins-slave-agent-on-windows-failed-with-connection-timeout)

Comment: No, its not working